# HTML and CSS rotating and zoomable 3D cube

Tags: jquery, html, css, 3d

I made a cube with html and css. Also, i put jquery to activate css classes on pressing the buttons. However, they are not working properly and also, if i want to rotate the cube in the same direction more than once, i need to press the button twice. How can i fix this? Also, when the cube has been rotated, i want the black side to stay to the side. Presently, every time i turn the cube, the back side is becoming black. Same thing with the Hello. Also, how can i add a zoom feature which zooms in and out of the cube when i scroll?
My code - http://pastebin.com/qZFfTsuG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code gets the effect you wanted. I have used different approach by using a variable `yAngle` to store current orientation. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4wdauL8/) of this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var yAngle = 0;
    
    $("#button_left").click(function(){
        yAngle = yAngle-90;
        $("section").css("transform",'rotateY('+yAngle+'deg)');
    });
    
    $("#button_right").click(function(){
        yAngle = yAngle+90;
        $("section").css("transform","rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)");
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap
{
    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}
.cube
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
.cube div
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(125,125,125,0.9);
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.back
{
    background: rgba(40,40,40,0.8);
    transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.right
{
    background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
    transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
    transform-origin: top right;
}
.left
{
    background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
    transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
    transform-origin: center left;
}
.top
{
    background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
    transform-origin: top center;
}
.bottom
{
    background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.front
{
    background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}
/*
@keyframes spin_left {
        from { transform: rotateY(0); }
        to { transform: rotateY(-90deg); }
}
.rotate-left {
        animation: spin_left 1s 1 linear;
}
@keyframes spin_right {
        from { transform: rotateY(0); }
        to { transform: rotateY(90deg); }
}
.rotate-right {
        animation: spin_right 1s 1 linear;
}
*/
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="wrap">
        <section class="cube">
                <div class="front">Hello</div>
                <div class="back"></div>
                <div class="top"></div>
                <div class="bottom"></div>
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="right"></div>
        </section>
</div>    
<input type="button" value="<--" id="button_left">
<input type="button" value="-->" id="button_right">
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is problematic ...

- You fetch `jquery.min.js` twice, when you only need it once.
- You have two `$('document').ready`-calls, when you only need one. You should place both your button-listeners in the same one.
- CSS `animation` is experimental, and you should add an extra css-entry with vendor prefixes for Chrome and Safari to work (`-webkit-animation:`).
- The double-click-problem: You must either remove your `rotate-left/right`-css class when the animation is finished (via JavaScript), or create an animation for the second click, when the `rotate-left/right`-css class is automatically removed by your current `toggleClass`-call ... The best solution will take some figuring out, to decide.

All-in-all many issues.

Comment: I fixed the first two problems. But still no luck. As for the third one, i'm using chrome and one arrow key is working while the other is not. Code - http://pastebin.com/3sbh4Pe5